# How to make Excel application load some xll files via vbs?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2003

I need to be able to load the xlls into an instance of Excel.

It is easy to do so using the GUI. Just use 'open file' dialog box and load the xll file.

However, how I can script this behaviour using vbs + COM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VBS you can do this:

```
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xl.RegisterXLL("analys32.xll") 'to load an XLL
xl.Workbooks.Open (xl.LibraryPath & "\analysis\atpvbaen.xla") 'to load an XLA
```